# How can highlight the searched test without using tag like 'span' in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need Javascript that searches a web page for a specific text and highlights it with css.
What makes this problem difficult: The solution must not modify the actual text in the HTML.

```
<p>This is a paragraph with the word find me in it.</p.>
```

If I provide the search string "me", I want this to be highlighted. Note that I cannot simply apply styling the `<p>`. In fact, there is no element to apply styling to that would allow me to highlight that word!

The obvious solution would be to modify the DOM like this:

```
<p>This is a paragraph with the word <span class="highlight">me</span> in it.</p>
```

However, this is not what I want!

Comment: Without modifying the actual HTML I see no way to highlight part of it

Comment: What happens to be the reason you can't add a span tag? I don't know if  you could get the desired result without adjusting the HTML, like @j08691 stated.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look. It highlights specified text without wrapping the text in a span.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```js
function highlightText(element, textToHighlight) {
  const innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
  const index = innerHTML.indexOf(textToHighlight);

  if (index >= 0) {
    element.innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) +
      "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + textToHighlight.length) +
      "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + textToHighlight.length);
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => highlightText(p, 'me'));
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph with the word find me in it.</p>
```

If not, you can do this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const textElement = document.getElementById('textParagraph');
  const highlightContainer = document.getElementById('highlightContainer');

  function createHighlightForWord(element, word) {
    const text = element.textContent;
    const wordIndex = text.indexOf(word);

    if (wordIndex === -1) return;
    const range = document.createRange();
    const textNode = element.firstChild;
    range.setStart(textNode, wordIndex);
    range.setEnd(textNode, wordIndex + word.length);
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    const highlight = document.createElement('div');
    highlight.classList.add('highlight');
    highlight.style.top = `${rect.top + window.scrollY}px`;
    highlight.style.left = `${rect.left + window.scrollX}px`;
    highlight.style.width = `${rect.width}px`;
    highlight.style.height = `${rect.height}px`;
    highlightContainer.appendChild(highlight);
    range.detach();
  }

  createHighlightForWord(textElement, 'me');
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<p id="textParagraph">This is a paragraph with the word find me in it.</p>
<div id="highlightContainer"></div>
```

Explanation: The script finds the position of the word 'me' in the paragraph. It uses the Range API to measure where the word is within the text node. A highlight element is created and absolutely positioned over the word based on these measurements.